# ConstraintLayout beta 5 ImageView scaling issues in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, beta, android-constraintlayout

Since I updated to `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta5` I'm observing strange behavior when using an `ImageView` that scales inside a `ConstraintLayout` used in an `RecyclerAdapter`

I've made a demo project with least steps to reproduce:

The row is pretty simple: a header and an image:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<View
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header"
    />
```

The adapter looks like this:

```
public class RecAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BooleanViewHolder> {

private List<Boolean> list;

public RecAdapter(ArrayList<Boolean> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public BooleanViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new BooleanViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BooleanViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.header.setBackgroundColor(list.get(position) ? Color.parseColor("#00FF00") : Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));

    holder.image.setImageDrawable(null);
    if (list.get(position)) {
        holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.image.setImageDrawable(holder.image.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.remove_me));
    } else {
        holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}


static class BooleanViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final ImageView image;
    private final View header;

    BooleanViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        header = itemView.findViewById(R.id.header);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    }
}
}
```

`RecyclerView` and adapter are initialized as follows:

```
     recView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recView);
//      final StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        ArrayList<Boolean> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(true);
        list.add(false);
        list.add(true);
        list.add(false);
        list.add(true);
        list.add(false);
        list.add(true);
        list.add(false);
        recView.setAdapter(new RecAdapter(list));
```

The demo functionality is:
if `true` header is colored in green and the image is displayed.
if `false` header is colored in red and the `ImageView` is hidden.

The results after swiping down and up on the RecyclerView:

using `beta-5`(left) and `beta-4` (right):

[image]

I did test with API 24 & API 19 using both `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` and `LinearLayoutManager`

I know this looks more like an issue report for Google ([AOSP issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=234189)), but I'll use that post for that purpose unless someone points out a mistake I made or a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by Google in the library's master branch and will be working properly after the next release.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in beta5, with `wrap_content`. I filed a bug and talked with a Google Engineer working on ConstraintLayout. He confirmed the bug, reproduced it and then in a couple of days he fixed it in `master` so I expect it will be fixed in the *next release* (unknown date).

The bug report is located [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=233909).

Notice it's `Fixed in master.` as of 2 days ago.

Comment: I think that the issues were unrelated, though similar. Google has merged this one to master as well as of 20 minutes ago. Anyways thanks for the reply